# Top Visitor Report for Sharepoint2010 Subsites

Tags: powershell, web-analytics, site-usage

how we can get top visitors report for SharePoint 2010 subsites.

For Site collection Top Visitor report I used method mentioned in below link

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4d6d921-d1e1-4177-9c87-3c30ef30e7f5/site-collection-top-visitor-report-showing-only-2000-users

Comment: I need Top Visitor report for each subsite in site collection

Comment: Dear Ganesh and Mohamed this is a different question I think because here I am asking about To Visitor for subsites.